# Is a mutex lock needed around a pointer variable?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pointers, mutex

Is a mutex lock needed around a section of code that involves pointer indirection (where the pointer points to data that is part of a critical section)? An example code:

```
struct list {
    int i;
    struct list *next;
};

int modify_second_elem(struct list *head, int val);
void * func1(void *ptr);
void * func2(void *ptr);

int modify_second_elem(struct list *head, int val) {

    if(head == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* Check to see if second element exists.
       Here, I am using indirection to get the next pointer.
       Would I need synchronization here? */
    if(head->next == NULL)
        return -1;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&list_lock);
    (head->next)->i = val;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_lock);

    return 0;

}

void * func1(void *ptr) {
    struct list *head;
    head = (struct list *) ptr;
    modify_second_elem(head, 4);
}

void * func2(void *ptr) {
    struct list *head;
    head = (struct list *) ptr;
    modify_second_elem(head, 6);
}

void main() {
    struct list *el1, *el2, *el3;
    pthread_t th1, th2;

    el1 = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
    el2 = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(list));
    el3 = (struct list *) malloc(sizeof(list));

    el1->i = 1;
    el1->next = el2;
    el2->i = 2;
    el2->next = el3;
    el3->i = 3;
    el3->next = NULL;

    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, &func1, (void *) el1);
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, &func2, (void *) el1);

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: A lock is need when you have a [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). Forget about pointers or no-pointers.

Comment: is this valid code? the argument list between the function declaration and its definition is different

Comment: `int modify_struct(struct s *sptr)` is different from `int modify_struct(s)`. personally i would not recognize the latter as a valid function. but maybe i'm missing something obvious here

Comment: @knittl You are right. I changed my code in the course of writing my question and changed a function invocation to the function definition and forgot to replace the variable with an argument list. I was even trying to explain away my mistake. Silly me. I have edited it now. Thanks. :)

Comment: no probs :) just wanted to make sure this wasn't something i've missed in C all that time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not enough information given to give a really good answer. How is `s` "published" to other threads? How do other threads "subscribe" to `s`? In what data structure are `struct s` objects stored?

So, I'll give a generic answer:

Every kind of data that is shared between threads needs synchronization. This includes shared pointers.

About pointers:

You may have heard that on some commonplace CPUs loads/stores of correctly aligned pointers are atomic (this is not the case for all CPUs or for all kinds of pointers, e.g: far pointers on x86 are non-atomic). Stay away from using this if you don't have a thorough understanding of your CPU/VM memory model, there are many subtle things that can go wrong if you don't take locks (locks provide pretty strong guarantees).

### Edit:

In your example, neither `th1` nor `th2` modifies the list, they only modify elements of the list. So, in this specific case, you don't need to lock the list, you just need to lock elements of the list (the pointer conceptually belongs to the linked list implementation).

In more typical cases, some threads would be traversing the list, while others would be modifying the list (adding and removing elements). This requires locking the list, or using some kind of lock-free algorithm.

There are several ways of doing this locking.

- Have a **global lock** on the list, and use it also for elements of the list.
- Use **hierarchical locking**, have a lock on the list, and a lock on every element. To read/modify an element, you would first take a lock on the list, find the element, take the element's lock, release the list's lock, process the element, and finally release the element's lock. This is useful if you need to do some complex processing on the element and don't want to prevent other threads from accessing the list. *You have to take care to always take the locks in the same order*, to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: I have modified the code in my question. Do you think that is sufficient for a more specific comment? Thanks.

Comment: I was looking at locks linearly. It's interesting to know that they can be applied hierarchically too. So, from what you have explained, if I were to have another thread that manipulates the list (add-after/add-before/delete element) then in that case I'll need to lock the `next` pointer as well?

Comment: You would take a lock on the list, which protects the whole list data structure (i.e. _all_ the next pointers, plus all the elements). Hierarchical locking can be seen as an optimization on the global lock above, it alllows more concurrency.

Answer (score 4):

Locks are used to protect [critical section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) in the code. If your variable is in critical section, then you will need to protect it with some kind of lock.

Comment: Thanks. I was unsure if a pointer to shared data is also critical.

Answer (score 2):

A lock is used to protect [critical sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). It has nothing to do with a variable being a pointer or not.

In your case, you don't need to lock that check. Because `s` is a parameter it cannot be accessed from outside your function. However, *the data pointed by it* is not local to your function, so you might need to lock access to that data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a novice and it never occurred to me that I am actually dealing with a local variable. In retrospect, my question looks really dumb now. No wonder Google didn't return any results.

Comment: I don't see any local variable there.

Comment: @ninjalj: Ok, it's a function parameter :P. My point still applies, though.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what other operations you may have on `s`. For example, another thread modifying value of `s->c` depending on what `s->i` is:

```
if (s->i == 1) {
    s->c = 'x';
} else {
    s->c = 'y';
}
```

In this case you cannot omit the mutex lock otherwise you may have both `s->i` set to 1 and `s->c` set to 'y'.